# Sorting and comparing dates in bash

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

I'm trying to find, save and compare "last change" date-time of files in 2 different directories and figure out which directory had the latest change.

I came this far:

```
find ./map -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -f "%Sm"
```

This prints all the "last change dates" of the files in a directory.

The output looks something like this:

```
Oct  5 12:07:59 2015
Aug 27 12:40:29 2015
Aug 27 12:40:42 2015
Aug 27 12:40:42 2015
Aug 27 12:40:40 2015
Aug 27 12:40:37 2015
Aug 27 12:40:35 2015
Aug 27 12:40:33 2015
```

I need to sort them, take the last one, do the same thing again for the other directory and then compare the outputs to figure out which one is the latest.

I have no idea how to sort these outputs since they have to be sorted by year, then by month, day...
And also I do not know how to convert these values into something that I can compare in a bash script...

Any ideas?

Comment: `find ./map -type f -printf "%A+ %p\\n"` will give you the dates in a more easily sortable format.

Comment: unknown primary or operator?

Comment: Don't use `xargs` where `-exec` is sufficient: `find ./map -type f -exec stat -f "%Sm" {} \;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try piping the data through `sort` first:

```
find /map -type f -print0 | sort | xargs -0 stat -f "%Sm"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to … figure out which directory had the latest change.

Why not let `ls` do the job?

```
/bin/ls -t `find map mop -type f` | head -1
```

Assuming your two directories are `map` and `mop`, this sorts the files in them by time and outputs the first, i. e. newest. Take the `dirname`, and you have what you want.